# webscrape star rating using beautifulsoup from webpage

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the star rating of each review in a dataframe for sentiment analysis.
https://www.mouthshut.com/product-reviews/Kotak-811-Mobile-Banking-reviews-925917218
This the webpage I am trying to scrape. I am fairly new to webscraping, so I prefer beautifulsoup as it is easier to understand.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = ""
Final = []
for x in range(0, 8):
    if x == 1:
        URL = "https://www.mouthshut.com/product-reviews/Kotak-811-Mobile-Banking-reviews-925917218"

    else:
        URL ="https://www.mouthshut.com/product-reviews/Kotak-811-Mobile-Banking-reviews-925917218-page-{}".format(x)

    r = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    reviews = []  # a list to store reviews

    # Use a CSS selector to extract all the review containers
    review_divs = soup.select('div.col-10.review')
    for element in review_divs :

        review = {'Review_Title': element .a.text, 'URL': element .a['href'], 'Review': element .find('div', {'class': ['more', 'reviewdata']}).text.strip()}
        reviews.append(review)

    Final.extend(reviews)

df = pd.DataFrame(Final)
```

I would really appreciate the help.
Thank You

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Jem I want to extract the star rating. I cant seem to figure out to get it

Answer (score 0):

You may add the following entry to your `review` dictionary to get all the
giving stars under `class=rating`.

```
'Stars' : len(element.find('div', "rating").findAll("i", "rated-star"))
```

```
                                 Review_Title  ... Stars
0   Why need permission for contact,  gallery  ...     1
1        Very dull marketing for open account  ...     1
2                                  Worst bank  ...     1
3   Good interface & can be easily accessible  ...     3
4                   Best digital Bank account  ...     4
5                 Better account for everyone  ...     4
6                 Feature full Mobile banking  ...     5
7                              Very good bank  ...     4
8     Above average online banking experience  ...     3
...
```

Comment: thank you soo much, this worked for me and I also understood the concept used in your code line.